# jenkins m2 release deploy only one artifact

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

using jenkins m2 release plugin automatically sends some request to maven-deploy-plugin. this enables deploy of all artifacts. How can I stop this and deploy only specific artifact?

Comment: what command are you using? what are your configuration for the plugin?

Comment: it is default configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by settings in pom.xml files of parent project (disable default deploy). Because parent is transefered to child - the deploys stop on all project.

after that I found the project which contained files i needed and supplied goal deploy:deploy-file and inside pom.xlm configured the goal.

m2 release plugin can send -Darguments="..." where you can set parameters for inner build. that's where I call deploy:deploy-file.

this is answer to close question.